# Calling stored procedure in mysql in PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a php script that is being called by an ajax post. I am getting the error 
**Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Escape\SendTestimony.php** on line **9**

Here is the paramaters

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

$message = $_POST['message'];

Here is line 9 where the error occurs. Thanks for any help.

```
mysql_query("CALL sp_CreateTestimony("$name.", "$message.")");
```

EDIT ADDED JQUERY AJAX CALL

```
 var parameters = {
                    'name': $('#cf_name').val(),
                    'message': $('#cf_message').val()
                }; //Use JSON to pass parameters into ajax calls  
                parameters = JSON.stringify(parameters); 


                //Make ajax call to post to database
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '../Escape/SendTestimony.php',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    data: parameters,
                    success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                        $('#ValidateTest').html('Thank-you!').css({ 'color': 'green' }).show();
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert(textStatus + ":" + errorThrown);}
                });
```

Comment: Is this an issue because you're putting quotes around $name and $message? Looks like it may be... try replacing them with single quotes.

Comment: Thank you that seem to do the trick. But now the parameters seem to be empty. I am getting Undefined index: name and Undefined index: message. Thanks for the help, I am a noob at php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should add dots before variables and single quotes around them:

```
mysql_query("CALL sp_CreateTestimony('".$name."', '".$message."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

stringify was the problem. I removed that and it fix the problem.